# How do you disable that button in some laptop keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I'm working with an HP laptop issued to me by work. It's got that extremely (to me) irritating button, that's surrounded by the G, H and B keys. The button allows one to move the mouse. **I HATE THAT BUTTON!!** After screwing up lots of code, documents, etc. because the cursor suddenly moves to a new location while I was typing and I'm left there wondering how in heck that happened. I think I've finally figured out that it is that button. (I'm sorry I don't know what it is called. I'm sure I could have found out how to do fix this myself, but I don't know what it's called.) So please, how do I disable it so that it won't cause the mouse to suddenly move on me?

Comment: The button is called a [pointing stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) or a [TrackPoint](https://xkcd.com/243/) (from IBM trademark).

Comment: On my Thinkpads, I pull the rubber cap of the trackpoint off.  That leaves the button still active, but below key-level (haha) so I don't accidentally hit it.  Also, I've found the mouse moving is mostly because of the trackpad being enabled, so I disable that when I've got an external mouse to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the track stick in the mouse settings, accessed from Control Panel.

By going to Control Panel, and selecting mouse, this is how I disable my track stick on a Lenovo laptop. Your UI may look a bit different since it's an HP, but you should be able to find the track stick settings in there.

[image]